# Serialize/Deserialize class containing byte array property into XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, .net-4.0

My data class that will be serialized into XML look like this:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "SPCFileInfo")]
[Serializable]
public class SPCFileInfoProtocol
{
    [XmlElement("CompanyCode")]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("FileName")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("FileVer")]
    public int FileVer { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("FileSize")]
    public long FileSize { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CreatedOn")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("LastUpdatedOn")]
    public DateTime LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("FileBytes")]
    public byte[] FileBytes { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my serialization utiltiy class

```
public static class XmlSerializer
{
    public static string SerializeToString<T>(T item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false); // no BOM in a .NET string
        settings.Indent = false;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, item);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static T DeserializeFromString<T>(string xmlString)
    {
        T item = default(T);

        try
        {
            using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer =
                new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                item = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

Serialization into XML works fine, but when I attempt to deserialize, I get the following exception:

> XMLException: There is an error in XML document. 
>   hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.

[Upon investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798033/the-invulnerable-xmlexception), I found out that certain character codes are not valid for XML document. Removing invalid characters is not an option since they constitute the bytes for a file.

My question is how do you serialize/deserialize a data class like above into XML without stripping invalid bytes? If this is not possible, what are some viable alternatives?

Edit: Upon request, here's the full stacktrace of the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
>   (1, 21933). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00,
>   is an invalid character. Line 1, position 21933.    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos,
>   Int32& outOrChars)    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementString()    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSPCCommandProtocol.Read2_SPCCommandProtocol(Boolean
>   isNullable, Boolean checkType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSPCCommandProtocol.Read3_SPCCommand()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader)    at
>   NextSPCFileUpdater.Utilities.XmlSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String
>   xmlString) in C:\Source
>   Codes\SPC\nextspc-fileupdater\NextSPCFileUpdater\Utilities\XmlSerializer.cs:line
>   48

And here's the new version of deserialization

```
public static T DeserializeFromString<T>(string xmlString)
{
    T item = default(T);

    try
    {
        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        using (XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader) { Normalization = false })
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            item = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, there are lots of characters that may not be present in an XML document.  These can be included in your data, however, using the proper escape sequence.

The default settings of the XmlTextReader cause it to mishandle this -- I think it interprets the escape sequences prematurely, but I'm not precisely certain.  If I recall correctly, the XmlSerializer will create an XmlTextReader to wrap the TextReader you pass it.  To override that, you need to create one yourself, setting its `Normalization` property of the XmlTextReader to `false`.

Regardless of whether my recollection of the causes of the problem is correct,  however, setting `Normalization` to `false` will solve your problem:

```
var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(textReader) { Normalization = false };
```

Or rather, in your case:

```
using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
using (XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader) { Normalization = false })
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer =
    new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    item = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);
}
```

As an aside, most will find your code far more readable if you use some `using` directives:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
using (XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader) { Normalization = false })
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    item = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);
}
```

Still more will find it more readable if you use `var` (though I have at least one colleague who disagrees):

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
using (var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader) { Normalization = false })
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    item = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);
}
```

Comment: Strange.. I'm getting an identical error even with normalization set to false.

Comment: @l46kok can you post your current code and the full text of the exception message, including the inner exception?

Comment: Code is quite long as it's handling socket communication but I'll try my best to crop out the relevant parts

Comment: @I just meant the changes you made to set Normalization to false.  The exception messages are more important.

Comment: @l46kok have you examined the string at position 21933?  Does it in fact contain a zero character?  I am unable to reproduce your error, perhaps because my byte array isn't the same as yours.

Comment: @l46kok my serializer is serializing the array in Base64, so the whole invalid character bit is perhaps related to something completely different.  (Also, as an aside, the SerializableAttribute is not necessary for xml serialization.)

Comment: Oh wow, for some reason Array.Copy is sometimes failing on copying buffer when bytes are received through socket. Time to investigate on why this is happening. Thanks for your help, I've accepted your answer